# How to pass php variable FORM data to mail handler?

Tags: php, forms, email, variables

I currently have a form built with HTML/PHP that has some variable data that I'm unable to pass to the mail handler. The inputs with the variable data are blank upon sending mail.

The HTML Form:

```
<form action="mail-handler.php" method="POST">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input name="T1" type="text" value="<?php print($_GET['firstname']); ?>" disabled="" />

    /*Non variable data still needs to pass*/
    <label>Phone*:</label>
    <input name="phone" type="tel" required="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The PHP Mail Handler:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];


$msgBody="First Name: $firstname\n
          Phone: $phone\n";
```

... and so on.

The form works for every input except the one with the variable data `$firstname`

How can I get the variable form value for "first name" to pass to the email handler?

Comment: You have a form field named `T1` and a `$_POST` key named `firstname`. How does the machine understand you mean the same thing? You need `<input name="T1"> ===> $_POST['T1`]`

Comment: Your firstname element has name "T1" instead of "firstname". So it is in the $_POST as T1

Comment: so, in mail handler should be `$T1 = $_POST['T1'];` ?

Comment: You are both correct, but that was not the main issue. Even after switching to the code you recommended, was still coming up blank. Apparently when the input is set in HTML to "disabled", it won't pass the info. I changed the input to "readonly" and it works like a charm. Anyone want to answer this and get credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while @Martin and @Adder were correct with the incorrectly assigned var value, even after changing the mail-handler, the data would still not pass through the email.

I found the culprit to actually be the bit of HTML used to keep someone from editing the stored information. I had set the form fields with the variable data to be `disabled=""`. Apparently this was the final block that was preventing the data transfer.

These are the changes I made to the code using the comment advice and changing the disabled status of the input.

```
<form action="mail-handler.php" method="POST">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input name="nameFirst" type="text" value="<?php print($_GET['firstname']); ?>" readonly="" />

    /*Non variable data still needs to pass*/
    <label>Phone*:</label>
    <input name="phone" type="tel" required="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP did not like the disabled status so `readonly=""` got the job done there. Then I changed the var names to better suit my needs:

```
$nameFirst = $_POST['nameFirst'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];


$msgBody="First Name: $nameFirst\n
          Phone: $phone\n";
```

This worked very well. Don't use `disabled=""` on a form in which you want to pass variable data, it won't work. Use `readonly=""` instead.